# Slicing Sparse Matrices in Scipy -- Which Types Work Best?

Tags: python, indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix, slice

The SciPy [Sparse Matrix tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Sparse) is very good -- but it actually leaves the section on slicing un(der)developed (still in outline form -- see section: "Handling Sparse Matrices").

I will try and update the tutorial, once this question is answered.

I have a large sparse matrix -- currently in dok_matrix format.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.dok_matrix((10**6, 10**6))
```

For various methods I want to be able to slice columns and for others I want to slice rows.  Ideally I would use advanced-indexing (i.e. a boolean vector, `bool_vect`) with which to slice a sparse matrix `M` -- as in:

```
bool_vect = np.arange(10**6)%2  # every even index
out = M[bool_vect,:]            # Want to select every even row
```

or

```
out = M[:,bool_vect] # Want to select every even column
```

First off, dok_matrices do not support this -- but I think it works (slowly) if I first cast to lil_matrices, via `sparse.lil_matrix(M)`

As far as I can gather from the tutorial -- to slice columns I want to use CSC and to slice rows I want to slice CSR. So does that mean I should cast the matrix `M` via:

```
M.tocsc()[:,bool_vect]
```

or

```
M.tocsr()[bool_vect,:]
```

I am kinda guessing here and my code is slow because of it.  Any help from someone who understands how this works would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If it turns out I should not be indexing my matrix with a boolean array, but rather a list of integers (indices) -- that is also something I would be happy to find out. Whichever is more efficient.

Finally -- this is a big matrix, so bonus points if this can happen in place / with broadcasting.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, so I'm pretty sure the "right" way to do this is:
if you are slicing columns, use tocsc() and slice using a list/array of integers.  Boolean vectors does not seem to do the trick with sparse matrices -- the way it does with ndarrays in numpy.  Which means the answer is.

```
indices = np.where(bool_vect)[0]
out1 = M.tocsc()[:,indices]
out2 = M.tocsr()[indices,:]
```

But question: is this the best way? Is this in place?

In practice this does seem to be happening in place -- and it is much faster than prior attempts (using lil_matrix).

Comment: If `M` is a format that does not have indexing (`coo` or `dok`) then this conversion is the right way.  But if `M` is already `csr` switching to `csc` just to do column indexing might not be worth it.  `sparse` indexing is a complicated business.

Comment: I can confirm that using csr for row slicing makes a huge difference