# Reduce a sparse matrix in python created from a noncontiguous coordinates lists

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, algebra, sparse-matrix

I am trying to build a biajacency matrix and find its eigenvalues. Because of the way the dataset is built the column and row numbers are noncontigious. This makes the matrix size to explode.
How could I purge totally empty rows and columns from a sparse matrix? The rest of the rows and columns should be renumerated in a contigious way.

The subject domain are buyers and sellers and their purchases. The buyes and sellers are represented with a random integer ID. These IDs are noncontigious. The dataset is the list of all purchases in the form of buyer_ID,seller_ID list in a CSV form.

here is my code

```
from sympy import *
import scipy
import csv
rows=[]
cols=[]
data=[]
with open('dataset.txt', 'rt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')              
    next(reader, None)  # skip the headers
    for row in reader:    
        rows.append(int(row[0]))
        cols.append(int(row[1]))
        data.append(1.0) # values were absent in the list of edges
print(len(rows))
print(len(set(rows)))
print(len(cols))
print(len(set(cols)))
edges_matrix = coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)))
print(edges_matrix.get_shape())
biajacency_matrix=bmat([[None,edges_matrix],[edges_matrix.transpose(),None]])
print(biajacency_matrix.get_shape())
scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.eigsh(biajacency_matrix,3,which='LM')
```

There are 303987 rows in my dataset, 50385 buyers and 125854 sellers. But because the IDs have a larger range the created edges_matrix is of a size (215115110, 215117581).

My biajacency (very sparse square) matrix becomes the size of 430232691
and the eigenvalue functions eigsh fails with Memory error. In fact majority of its columns and rows are totally empty.

How could I easily renumerate the buyers and sellers to reduce the size of the biajacency matrix to 50385+125854=176249? In other words to leave only the rows that have at least one value.

I could do the same thing on a database building a dictionary table and joining to the original dataset to replace the IDs. But may be this can be done easier in Python?

SOLUTION:

```
baj_m=biajacency_matrix.tocsr()[list(set(rows)),:][:,list(set(cols))] # drop all zero rows and columns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of removing both empty rows and empty columns from a sparse matrix.

```
A=sparse.rand(100,100,format='csr')
I=np.nonzero(A.sum(0))[1].A.flatten()
J=np.nonzero(A.sum(1))[0].A.flatten()
```

`I` and `J` are the indexes of the columns and rows with at least one value (or technically sum !=0, which is the same thing for floats).

```
A 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

A[J,:][:,I] 
<64x62 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The reduced matrix has the same number of nonzero elements, but in a reduced shape.

This isn't the complete solution for your case, but I think it gives you a tool that can be adapted.

Note that only a few of the sparse formats allows indexing like this.  Fortunately the ones that are good for eigenvalue calculations also implement indexing.

Comment: Actually it is known which rows and columns are non-zero because of the way the matrix is created. This information is stored in rows and cols lists in my example. Is this what you use in the A[J,:][:,I] part? The I,J calculation takes some time, I wonder if that is needed at all.

Comment: `I` and `J` are just the columns and rows that I want to keep.  It doesn't matter how they are derived.

Comment: just to keep this here as it discusses the advanced slicing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491548/scipy-do-sparse-matrices-support-advanced-indexing