# Why does scipy.take not work with a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

If I do the same with a `numpy.zeros` matrix it works. But with a scipy sparse matrix it doesn't work. Why?

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy as sp
a = sparse.lil_matrix((3,3), dtype=int)
a[0,0] = 0
a[1,1] = 1
a[2,2] = 2
b = a.sum(0)
bo = (-b).argsort()
ao = sp.take(a, bo, axis=1)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds
```

Why isn't that working. Can please someone tell me how to fix it? Or is it not possible with a scipy sparse matrix?

Comment: A sparse matrix is not a subclass of `np.ndarray`.  So you can't count of `numpy` functions working.  Use `sparse` functions and methods where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expect `scipy.sparse` matrices to behave exactly the same as dense numpy matrices or arrays.

For one thing, `scipy.sparse` matrices support only a subset of the indexing operations that can be applied to dense arrays/matrices, and this subset depends on the particular sparse format in question. For example, you can't apply slice indexing to a `coo_matrix`, you can only apply fancy indexing over a single axis of a `dok_matrix` etc. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14492151/1461210) for some more discussion of these limitations.

In your particular case, you can use fancy indexing in place of `np.take`:

```
ao = a[:, np.ravel(bo)]
# or ao = a[:, bo.flat]
# or ao = a[:, bo.A1]
```

However, not every sparse matrix format will support this kind of indexing, which probably explains why sparse matrices lack a `.take` method and are incompatible with `numpy.take`.

Comment: `bo` is a dense matrix, a 2d column vector.  `a[:,bo[0]]` is another way of reducing its dimensionality so it can be used on the last dimension of `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj That won't work without first casting `bo` to an ndarray. `bo` is a matrix, so `bo[0].shape == (1, 3)` rather than `(3,)`.

Comment: oops, should have recommended `a[:,bo.A1]` instead.

Comment: Thank you ali_m, it works, but it is very, very, very slow. So I can't use it.

Comment: If you're indexing by column then you probably shouldn't be using a `lil_matrix`, which is a row-based format. Try making `a` a `csc_matrix` instead (e.g. `a = a.tocsc()`).

Comment: I did and got a warning that a csc is very slow, I should use a lil_matrix :)

Comment: Changing the sparsity structure of a CSC matrix is indeed slow (e.g. when you are setting individual elements of `a` using `a[i,j] = c`). However, indexing columns will be *much* faster with a CSC matrix. Usually you would use LIL for constructing sparse matrices, then convert them to either CSR or CSC before performing arithmetic operations, matrix-vector products, row/column slicing etc.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the other answers a bit.  `np.take` (`sp.take` is the same thing) does:

```
try:
    take = a.take
except AttributeError:
    return _wrapit(a, 'take', indices, axis, out, mode)
return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
```

In other words, it tries to perform

```
a.take(bo, axis=1)
```

But `a.take` returns an attribute error. `a`, the sparse matrix does not have a `take` method.  And trying to convert `a` for array with `np.array(a)` doesn't work either - it just wraps the sparse matrix in a 0d object array.  That's why we get the `index` out of bounds error.

With the `lil` format, the matrix is stored as two lists, or most specifically object arrays of lists, one sublist per row.

```
In [620]: a.data
Out[620]: array([[1], [2], [3]], dtype=object)

In [621]: a.rows
Out[621]: array([[0], [1], [2]], dtype=object)
```

`a.__getitem__` is the function that performs the indexing.  It converts that fancy `numpy` like indexing into list comprehensions.  In contrast to arrays, there's not fast compiled indexing.

Note that if I first convert `a` to a dense array, this reordering goes a lot faster.  Even the round trip is faster.

```
In [626]: b0=(-b.A1).argsort()
In [627]: timeit a[:,b0].A
1000 loops, best of 3: 705 us per loop

In [628]: timeit a.A[:,b0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.3 us per loop

In [630]: timeit sparse.lil_matrix(a.A[:,b0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 483 us per loop
```

So if memory allows it may be more efficient to convert your sparse matrix to an array, index and otherwise manipulate it, and the convert back to sparse.

Comment: Thank you hpaulj. At the moment I'm using numpy array with numba and it is pretty fast, but it needs a lot of memory space. So I hoped with scipy I could lower it, but it is to slow :(

Comment: If `a` is large then a better option would be to convert it to a `csc_matrix` for faster column-based indexing

Comment: At least with this sample, indexing on `csc` is a bit faster than `lil` - if you don't take count the `tocsc` time.  Include the conversion and it's a bit slower.

Comment: Sure - for a single column indexing operation on a 3x3 matrix! If `a` is large enough that it won't fit in memory as a dense matrix then I would be willing to bet that converting it to CSR first would be faster, even factoring in the cost of conversion and assuming only a single column indexing operation.

Answer (score 0):

`spicy.take` doesn't seem to implement logic for sparse matrices. However, most of the functionality of the `take` function can be implemented using fancy indexing. In your case, I believe this gives you what you want:

```
ao = a[:, bo.flat]
```

Here, the `bo.flat` is a simple way to convert the `bo` matrix to a simple iterator.