# Selecting rows in scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to select the rows corresponding to some given indices in a scipy sparse matrix? The dummy approach does not work:

`sparse.eye(3)[:2, :]`

returns

`TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491548/scipy-do-sparse-matrices-support-advanced-indexing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352280/slicing-sparse-matrices-in-scipy-which-types-work-best). Although some things might have changed, it's important to understand that there are 7 different sparse-matrix types and all behave differently (in regards to some operations). Then you can try for example ```sparse.eye(3, format='csr')[:2,:]```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking a question like this, you should say more than 'returns error'.  What error?  That matters.

But I'll do that work for you:

```
In [143]: m =sparse.eye(3)
In [144]: m
Out[144]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [145]: m[:2,:]
...
TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

The error is significant.  It tells us that this particular sparse format has not implemented indexing.  We'd get the same error with the common `coo` format.  But with `csr` (or `lil`) format, indexing works:

```
In [146]: m =sparse.eye(3, format='csr')
In [147]: m
Out[147]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [148]: m[:2,:]
Out[148]: 
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [149]: _.A
Out[149]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

When generating a sparse matrix I like to display it's `repr`, which tells me the format and the size.  `print(m)` (`str`) shows the values in coo style.

`sparse.eye` produces `dia` format as the default, since the nonzero values are all on one diagonal.  Other sparse functions produce different default formats.

---

`dia` page shows a `getrow` method:

```
In [153]: sparse.eye(3).getrow(1)
Out[153]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

But notice the format of the returned matrix - csr, not dia.  The formats have methods that readily convert among each other.  Some operations do the necessary conversion for us.

Comment: Yes, actually I don't know how to write the whole snippet with inputs and outputs in stackoverflow, I'll try to figure it out.